# ReactiveCocoa: why subscriber has "sendNext" method rather "receiveNext" method

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm learning ReactiveCocoa and understand that `RACSignal` must be subscribed to a `RACSubscriber` for the signal to **send** the event. It is clear that `RACSignal` **send** event to `RACSubscriber` and   `RACSubscriber` **receive** event from `RACSignal`. However, when you customize your own RACSignal by the following code:

```
RACSignal *racsignal = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable* (id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
    //why subsriber "sendNext" not "receiveNext"?
    [subscriber sendNext:@100];
    return nil;
}];
```

The RACSubscriber protocol has `sendNext` method which confuses me because the method name of `receiveNext` should be more appropriate from my understanding. Can any body help me to clarify that?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the object implementing the `RACSubscriber` protocol doesn't consume the events, but forwards them to all subscribers. In your case there is only one, but the great thing about the `RACSignal` is that it can be observed from different objects and threads.

So you are right that the naming of `RACSubscriber` might be a bit misleading, but I wouldn't put to much attention on that, just as the documentation say:

> You generally shouldn't need to implement this protocol. +[RACSignal
>   createSignal:], RACSignal's subscription methods, or RACSubject should
>   work for most uses.